# Failed to load chart.js in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the chart.js to display bar charts etc using Angular and in the main index.html I have included the chart.js in many ways still none works if you have any alternative of chart.js while making Dashboard using Angular, Please let me know,Xd

Comment: Hi Dipesh and Welcome to StackOverflow.  You might want to review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular, what errors are you getting?  What does your code look like?  Without that, its unclear that even a list of alternative libraries would be helpful.

Comment: Try [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) which is an angular wrapper for charts.js. I personally like [ngx-charts](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/) more.